# 「Copy Syntax Highlight for OS X」がAtomの右クリックに出てこない

Tags: macos, atom-editor

「Copy Syntax Highlight for OS X」をインストールしまして、
Atomの右クリックで使いたいのですが、
項目が出てきません。

[http://www.moongift.jp/2015/11/copy-syntax-highlight-for-os-x-シンタックスハイライトを適用してコピ/](http://www.moongift.jp/2015/11/copy-syntax-highlight-for-os-x-%E3%82%B7%E3%83%B3%E3%82%BF%E3%83%83%E3%82%AF%E3%82%B9%E3%83%8F%E3%82%A4%E3%83%A9%E3%82%A4%E3%83%88%E3%82%92%E9%81%A9%E7%94%A8%E3%81%97%E3%81%A6%E3%82%B3%E3%83%94/)

テキストエディタやsafari上では、項目が出て、正しく使えます。

Comment: 関連 (atomのissueです): ["Enable native Services menu on OS X"](https://github.com/atom/atom/issues/3204) -- atom/atom -- GitHub

Comment: 関連 (atomのissueです): ["Enhance Atom's Mac Services support to include text services (editor not NSText)"](https://github.com/atom/atom/issues/10213)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Atomのコンテキストメニュー(右クリックででるメニュー)はAtom上で独自に制御されており、OSが提供するコンテキストメニューを表示するようにはできておりません。「Copy Syntax Highlight for OS X」以外にも「サービス(Service)」の項目自体がなく、その他「スピーチ(Speech)」等も無いのがわかるかと思います。全てのメニューがAtom独自にカスタマイズされているからです。

では、OSが提供するコンテキストメニューを表示するようにするにはどうすれば良いのかというと、設定には表示させるような項目がありませんのでパッケージで実現するしかないと思われます。しかし、そのようなパッケージも見つかりませんでしたので作るしか無いと思います。JavaScriptの知識があれば誰でも作れますので、チャレンジしてみて下さい(実際はCoffeeScriptまたはTypeScript、Babel(ES6以降)で作ることを推奨します)。

Comment: ありがとうございます！copy-with-syntaxというAtomのパッケージがありました！https://atom.io/packages/copy-with-syntax　ただ、Atom上でエラーが出てうまく使えないみたいです。